# Org mode: include LaTeX bibliography in the TOC

Tags: org-mode, org-export

This question is related to [ox-bibtex](https://github.com/yyr/org-mode/blob/master/contrib/lisp/ox-bibtex.el).

The snippet

```
#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: main abbrv
```

prints out an unnumbered section "Reference" excluded from the TOC in both LaTeX & html export.

Is there a portable & Org mode specific way to include bibliography as a section in the TOC?

Comment: Not with `ox-bibtex` AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this portably in Org mode AFAIK.

This is only for LaTeX - if I figure out the HTML export, I'll edit, but at this point that's unlikely.

`ox-bibtex` translates bibliography specs like this

```org
#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: path/to/acm-comp-surveys.bib plain
```

to the following LaTeX code:

```latex
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{/path/to/acm-comp-surveys.bib}
```

and when you run `bibtex` on that, you will produce a `.bbl` file which looks like this:

```latex
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{Finerman:1969:EN}
Aaron Finerman.
\newblock An editorial note.
\newblock {\em ACM Computing Surveys}, 1(1):1--1, March 1969.

\end{thebibliography}
```

If you look in the `article.cls` file, you find a definition of `thebibliography` environment that starts out like this:

```latex
 \newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
     ...
```

i.e. an unnumbered section with name `\refname`, which happens to be defined like this:

```latex
\newcommand\refname{References}
```

That explains what you see.

But this means that all of this is under the control of LaTeX and not under the control of Org mode. So your only avenue of modifying things is to change the LateX and the easiest way to do that is to redefine `thebibliography` environment to do what you want - just copy the original definition into a file `mybib.sty` with a couple of modifications: first, use `\renewenvironment` since you are redefining an existing environment, second, use an unstarred section to make it numbered and third, change the title to whatever you want - I hardwire it to `Bibliography` here - the rest is copied verbatim:

```latex
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section{Bibliography}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
```

Now add

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{mybib}
```

at the top of your Org mode file and export again. That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I will find time to report it in the mailing list.